# "To the rescue" in German

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

We have a common phrase in English : "to the rescue", to describe the act of swooping in and saving the situation. I want to say "German to the rescue" to describe the process whereby the German vocabulary in this case swoops in to save the situation. Google's translate gives me :

> "Deutsch zur Rettung"

but this feels like it's missing a preposition.

What would be the correct way to say "German to the rescue"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indeed sounds odd to German ears and the English original instantly mentions itself in the back of your head.

You could say

> (Mein) Deutsch eilt zu Hilfe
>
> (Mein) Deutsch eilt zur Rettung
>
> (Mein) Deutsch rettet den Tag (saves the day)

Still, these lacks the super hero association of the English phrase.

I would go with the original, I've heard this used by other Germans as well

> Deutsch to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to my mind was an old Disney Show "[Chip und Chap – Die Ritter des Rechts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo87FQZkfa4)" (Chip ’n Dale: Rescue Rangers), because Chip always said

> Rettungstruppe, auffi! (original: "Rescue Rangers, away" - not 100% sure about the english quote ^^)

meaning "Guys (and gals) get up and let's do this".

From my point of view this fits "to the rescue" and a lot of 90's kids will get the reference ;) .

So why not (in colloquial language)

> Deutsch, auffi!
>
> Deutsche Sprache, auffi!

---

And in addition to @infinitezero's answer:

> Deutsch auf zur Rettung!
>
> Deutsche Sprache auf zur Rettung!

Comment: I watched the show and would just stare at you with a puzzled look.

Comment: @infinitezero nicht das beste Beispiel, aber [siehe hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrfLg7n70oA&t=2m10s) ^^